# How to prevent some users in Windows 7 from accessing sites other than a set of certain sites?

Tags: blocking, internet-security

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate with some user credentials on a single computer. 
I want to prevent some users from accessing sites other than `*.stackexchange.com` and `stackoverflow.com`. How to do this without installing an additional software from 3rd party?

Comment: Are the computers part of a Microsoft domain?

Comment: @KCotreau: No, my computer is directly connected to ISP.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "white-list" (ie. limit activity to a specific list).

Comment: Are you really blocking them from everything except Stack Exchange or is this just your example? XD

Comment: @Shinrai: Yes. Only SE and SO are allowed in my house. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I figured out a way. Most people do this by editing the HOSTS file, but that would limit not one user, but all of them. On the other hand, proxy settings are by user.

So for Internet Explorer, go to `Tools>Internet Options>Connections>LAN Settings` and check `"Use a proxy server for your LAN"`, and set it to `127.0.0.1 port 80`, then click advanced, and add only the sites you want them to access (I would leave out the www, and just use the domain itself, separated by semi-colons for multiple domains). Please note that you may need to add any sites that the site you want to use accesses to work.

Also note this is very easy to change if they are local administrators.

I tested this with Windows 7 Ultimate, and it works.

[image]

Comment: I tried the same for Firefox, but it does not have an exceptions list, so I don't think it can be done if that is the browser you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Windows 7 Parental Controls](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/parental-controls). It should allow you o control web site access for users other than administrator.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. I just looked at this feature for the first time. It cannot limit by site. It only limits by time, by application and by game rating. As a note: This feature/tool is also disabled if the computer is part of a domain.

Answer (score 0):

For windows, proxy is definitely the right way to do this if you don't want to deal with Microsoft cloud services like Parental controls. Last time I tried, Parental controls required setting your windows password to be the same as a Microsoft cloud account. This was a fundamentally bad idea IMO so that was a non-starter for me.

I have successfully set up a Squid proxy server on my local windows machine where users have different rules for sites available on the same machine.

To do this, install [Squid http proxy](http://squid.diladele.com/) and add the following to the squid.conf:

ACL entries:

```
acl video_domains dstdomain .youtube.com .vimeo.com .googlevideo.com
acl port_kids localport 3128
acl port_parents localport 3129
```

Access rules:

```
http_access deny port_kids video_domains
```

Listening entries:

```
http_port 3128
http_port 3129
```

Now configure the parents accounts to use proxy at 127.0.0.1 port 3129 and point the kids on proxy 127.0.0.1 port 3128. The kids don't have access to blocked video sites but the parents will. I think the only issue here is that not all browsers respect global proxy settings. Chrome uses the global settings but I believe Firefox has its own proxy config.

This methodology should work with Windows, Mac or linux desktops and can be easily tweaked to suite the usecase asked by the OP.